# Azure Function Linked Service ARM template deployment

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, linked-service

I am deploying a Azure Function **Linked Service** through CICD pipeline, I am unable to deploy it to ADF with its function key

```
 "LS_AF_xxxx_properties_typeProperties_functionAppUrl": {
  "value": "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net"
},
 "LS_AF_xxxx_properties_typeProperties_encryptedCredential": {
            "value": "uiaLtjo8ACh5zYAparmGIhLh_Bhvk4VbsgcGLFWWSFNzAzFumEPZ9w=="
        }
```

The error is as below

'The template parameters 'LS_AF_xxxx_properties_typeProperties_encryptedCredential' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment.

Is there a way to create an azure function linked service with function key through ARM template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196878/azure-arm-template-parameters-for-parametrized-linked-service?rq=2 Took help of this one , exporting ARM template and view the code.

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, I agree with your comment and the [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196878/azure-arm-template-parameters-for-parametrized-linked-service?rq=2) you shared to export the ARM template of Linked Azure Function service and then edit it accordingly and use it in your Azure Devops ARM task.***

**I created one Linked Service with Azure Function like below:-**

[image]

Then **I Exported the ARM template** and **used it in my Azure Devops pipeline**:-

***Go to Manage tab in ADF > Source control > ARM Template > Export***

[image]

**Uploaded the Exported File in Azure repository:-**

[image]

**Exported ARM code with Function:-**

```json
{
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/pipeline15')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Azure Function1",
                        "type": "AzureFunctionActivity",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "functionName": "HttpTrigger1",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "headers": {}
                        },
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureFunction1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "elapsedTimeMetric": {},
                    "cancelAfter": {}
                },
                "annotations": []
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
```

Utilize the Exported Linked ARM template in your CI/CD pipeline like below:-

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'subscription(xxxxe2b6e97cb2a7)'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxx598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7'
    resourceGroupName: siliconrg54
    location: 'Australia East'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_functionARMADF/factory/pratikdemofact_ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_functionARMADF/factory/pratikdemofact_ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
```

[image]